# error: " Attempt to reference field of non-structure array." in Matlab? error snap at end of code

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am writing a MATLAB code for detection of different color toys

I will be using below image in my code with name"toys.jpg"

[image]

My matlab code is as follow

```
clc;clear all;close all;
%Making matrix for 4 colors
MatrixR=[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1];
MatrixG=[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1];
MatrixB=[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1];
%B,Blue,G,C,R,P,Y,W
RGBMatrix=uint8(255*((cat(3,MatrixR,MatrixG,MatrixB))));
%Converting these matrix to Gray
GrayVersion=((rgb2gray(RGBMatrix)));
%Plotting
subplot 211
imshow(RGBMatrix,[0 255]);
title('RGB matrix of toys color');
subplot 212
imshow(GrayVersion,[0 255]);
title('Grayscale mapping of RGB matrix');
%Reading ToyImage
ToyImage=uint8(imread('toys.jpg'));
%Placing Cursor
dcm_obj1 = datacursormode(figure);
imshow(ToyImage,[]);
datacursormode on
fprintf('Select the toy from the Image Displayed\n');
waitforbuttonpress;
c_info = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj1);
position=c_info.Position; %extracting position for finding toy
grayValueFromImage=double(ToyImage(position(2),position(1)));
%Formula
red=abs(double(GrayVersion(5))-grayValueFromImage); green=abs(double(GrayVersion(3))-grayValueFromImage);
blue=abs(double(GrayVersion(2))-grayValueFromImage); yellow=abs(double(GrayVersion(7))-grayValueFromImage);
%Condition
minimumAmongArray=min([red,blue,green,yellow]);
fprintf('At Position \n');
disp(position);
if(minimumAmongArray==red)
fprintf('The selected toy has Red Color\n');
end
if(minimumAmongArray==green)
fprintf('The selected toy has Green Color\n');
end
if(minimumAmongArray==blue)
fprintf('The selected toy has Blue Color\n');
end
if(minimumAmongArray==yellow)
fprintf('
The selected toy has Yellow Color\n');
end
```

But when i try to execute above code, i get error: "  Attempt to reference field of non-structure array"

[image: t end]

Comment: The exception not only contains the cause ("Attempt to reference field of non-structure array") but also the line of code where the exception occurs. Please include this information, especially with such lengthy code examples.

Comment: please check now

Comment: This code works for me in MATLAB 2017b

Comment: What version of MATLAB do you use and what does `which getCursorInfo` return?

Comment: my matlab version is 2011b

Comment: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\toolbox\matlab\graphics\@graphics\@datacursormanager\getCursorInfo.m  % graphics.datacursormanager method